# Make an Actor send a poisonpill to itself when using pipe pattern

Tags: scala, akka

I have the following actor

```
class FooActor(name: String) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: Bar => 
      val x : Future[List[T]] = makeDBCall()
      x pipeTo sender()
    case _ => 
  }
}
```

what I want is that after pipeTo operation has successfully send the list to the sender the actor instance terminates itself.

I am a little hesitant in putting a self ! poisonpill message just in the next line to pipe to because I don't understand how pipeTo works.

if pipeTo blocks till the future completes, then perhaps putting the self ! poisonpill in the next line is safe.

But if pipeTo is nonblocking and it executes by means of a callback, then calling self ! poisonpill in the next line will prematurely kill the actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how pipeTo [is implemented](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/PipeToSupport.scala):

```
  final class PipeableFuture[T](val future: Future[T])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {
    def pipeTo(recipient: ActorRef)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Future[T] = {
      future andThen {
        case Success(r) ⇒ recipient ! r
        case Failure(f) ⇒ recipient ! Status.Failure(f)
      }
    } 
// ...
```

Basically it sends the message to the recipient after the future is completed and returns another future. So it is asynchronous and placing self ! PoisonPill at the next line won't work as you expect.

Something like this should do the trick though:

```
x.pipeTo(sender()).onSuccess { case _ =>
  self ! PoisonPill
}
```